# How to prevent Fluent Validation from validating the model in certain condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have two submit buttons with different names on the form. In the controller
I have a single HttpPost action method that I invoke when either of the two submit buttons are clicked. Here's the internals of the action method:

```
public ActionResult Save(Document model){
    if(Request["btnSave"]!=null){
       if (ModelState.IsValid){
         //go ahead and save the model to db
       }
    }else{//I don't need the model to be validated here
       //save the view values as template in cache
    }
}
```

So, when the button with name "btnSave" is clicked I need the model to be validated before saving it to db but if the other button is clicked, I don't need any validation as I just save the form values in the cache to later call them back. Obviously I don't need to validate anything in this case. I use Fluent Validation. My problem is I get warnings no matter which button I press. Can I control when FV should validate the model?

Comment: Do you need to prevent validation on client-side when submitting form or in view returned after action execution?

Comment: In view returned after action execution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal: you want to prevent any server-side validation rules execution in second button click case?

Comment: Yes, I don't need validation to work when the second button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add property `btnSave` to your model:

```
public class Document
{
    public string btnSave {get; set;} // same name that button to correctly bind
}
```

And in your validator use conditional validation:

```
public class DocumentValidator : AbstractValidator<Document>
{
    public DocumentValidator()
    {
        When(model => model.btnSave != null, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(...); // move all your document rules here
        });

        // no rules will be executed, if another submit clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Haaaa, that's a very good idea. In fact I was close to that, I just didn't know that I could write a "standalone" When that would cover all the validation logic.

Comment: Here you disable it based on a logic on the UI, what would be nice is to disable at the level of the action method, do you know how to do it? I am looking for that solution